# How to bind to an attribute that has dashes in its name in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, .net-5

All the examples show how to use `@bind-attributename` to create two-way binding in blazor. But what if the attributename is `attribute-name` or worse: `data-attribute-name`? I keep getting error messages in Visual Studio informing me that it cannot resolve symbol 'bind'.

We use custom WebComponents that have properties that I want to bind to, like this:

```html
@foreach(var item in Items)
{
    <smart-multi-select-checkbox data-checkbox-details="@item"
                                 data-checked="@item.IsChecked">
    </smart-multi-select-checkbox>
}
```

I need the `data-checked` attribute to be bound two-way. Or, if that's not possible, I need to catch the custom event `data-check-changed`. But that's also not turning out to be very straight-forward.

Comment: not really sure if i understand your question an attribute is a representation of a property in a class and they can't have "-" in it.

Comment: Well, for some reason the `@bind` part goes red in my Visual Studio as soon as I add the dash after `data`. So `@bind-data`: all good; `@bind-data-checked`: @bind goes red.
I just assumed it was having issues with the second dash, as it goes red immediately when I add it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, if you are using a binding in the form of `@bind-checked=@item.IsChecked`, then your component/element needs to have a corresponding `checkedChanged` event that fires when `checked` is changed. Blazor specifically looks for {attributeName}Changed.  I believe that some of the standard elements don't need this because they are hardwired in Blazor automatically.

However, if you have a non-standard attribute, Blazor has no way of knowing where the change notifications are going to come from.  So you need to add a `@bind-checked:event="nameOfEvent"` to the element/component, too.  The following compiles fine for me (and `ViewModel.Question` is a real object, but `data-test` and `OnChange` are made up):

```
<div @bind-data-test=@ViewModel.Question @bind-data-test:event="OnChange">test</div>
```

Comment: And if you're still getting errors, make sure you have a @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web somewhere.

Comment: But what if that change event is a customevent from javascript, using dispatch? It doesn't seem to like the `data-check-changed` custom event.

Comment: It's possible the event has to begin with "on" as in "ondata-check-changed" for Blazor to recognize it as an event.  Try renaming your event and see if that's the case.  (At least to know if this is true)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0